# Vmware Ubuntu resize partition

Tags: partitioning, disk, resize

Currently, I want to resize the partition of my Vmware Ubuntu. But I got the following error, when I use gparted to grow the size of sda5. Waiting for someone can give some hints. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You have to extend sda2 first. sda5 is contained within sda2

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!